# Determine if an Event Handler Method is wired to an Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, timer, event-handling

I'm not sure if it's a good idea, and this is probably going to end up as more of an academic exercise, so bear with me:

Let's say I was making a UserControl (as I am), that will every X seconds (using a Timer) look for a text file and display that information within this UserControl.  Let's call this control MyUserControl.

To rehash the basic:

I would have this Timer as a member variable of this control, and have code that looks like:

```
this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
```

And an event handler method that looks like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Read text-file and do lots of goodness.
}
```

Cool, so now I can set a public property of MyUserControl to some elapsed time, and just by plopping this control on my Form, I have a nice little control updating itself.  Neat.

Here's the thing that got me curious:

The Form I'm going to plop it on already has a Timer.  So why have two competing timers?  I'd love for there to be a way for MyUserControl to only use it's internal timer if it's needed (for example, plopping it on another Form that doesn't already have a Timer).

I suppose I can make the MyUserControl timer1_Tick public like this here:

```
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Read text-file and do lots of goodness.
}
```

And then, because these things are multicast, do something like this here in the form:

```
this.theFormTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.theFormTimer_Tick);
this.theFormTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(MyUserControlObject.timer1_Tick);
```

And also set a member variable of MyUserControl to not enable itself.

But is there some slicker way of doing this?  Can I determine somehow that the event handler method in MyUserControl was already wired to the Form Timer's tick event?  Or use some other type of approach than what I'm suggesting?

Thanks!  (apologies if this ends up being a duplicate, my google-fu may be bad today)

Comment: There is no point in doing this.

Comment: You aren't concerned with the two timers?  I wasn't sure if I should be.

Comment: First, you probably shouldn't worry about it. A timer is a really lightweight component. Second, what if the period of the other timer were 1 second. Or 1 hour. And your component wants to update once per minute?

Comment: Yes, I would only utilize the form's timer if I wanted them to have the same elapsed time.  One caveat: although this is classified under "WinForms", I'm actually using Visual WebGUI.  So, I think, once I compile and run, the Timer actually becomes the equivalent of a javascript's SetInterval.  Not sure if that makes a difference in it being "lightweight" or not.  Anyhow, it does look like people aren't concerned.  I just wanted to double-check.

Comment: And of course if anyone wants to answer as an academic exercise, or someone wants to answer so I can green check-mark something, I'm cool with that too!

Answer (score 1):

Not discussing if you should or shouldn't do this, but to answer the question, I'd do it this way:

```
//add a handler
timer.Tick += timer_tick;

//...

//check if timer_tick is wired to Tick
if (timer.Tick.GetInvocationList().Contains (timer_tick))
{
    //do something
}
```

I haven't tested it, but that's what I'd try.

Comment: FYI, I'm not doing it.  In addition, I even prefaced this question with "I'm not sure it's a good idea".  Lastly, for me, this was more of an academic exercise to see what's possible.  Anyhow ... just for haha's I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: FYI, The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Tick' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=.  I gave it about 10 minutes to try to work through this and moved on to production code!

Comment: Thanks for trying this. I did tried as well, and you actually can invoke GetActivationList() from within the class the event is defined.